# PHP form contact, with checkboxs, error 500

Tags: php, forms, checkbox, contact-form

Can anybody help me! This php doesn't work in my web, doesn't send email, if i change die(error), the page say to me that..
[image]

There is de php action

```php
    <?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$email = $_POST['mail'];
$Title = $_POST ['position/title'];
$company = $_POST ['company'];
$location = $_POST ['location'];
$telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
$services = $_POST['services'];
$string = join(" \r\n ", $services);
$timeframe = $_POST['timeframe'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];
$learn = $_POST['learn'];
        $message = '<html><body>';
        $message .= '<img src="http://www.corbisglobal.com/assets/web/img/contact-CG-logo.png" />';
        $message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666; border : 1px;" cellpadding="10">';
        $message .= "<tr style='background: #ddd;'><td><strong>Name:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['name']) .  "</td></tr>";
         $message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>Lastname:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['lastname']) . "</td></tr>";
        $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Email:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['mail']) . "</td></tr>";
         $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Title/Position:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['position/title']) . "</td></tr>";
        $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Company:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['company']) . "</td></tr>";
        $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Location:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['location']) . "</td></tr>";
         $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Services:</strong> </td><td>" . join(" \r\n, ", $services) . "</td></tr>";
         $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Timeframe:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['timeframe']) . "</td></tr>";
         $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Learn about Corbis:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['learn']) . "</td></tr>";
        $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Comments:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['comments']) . "</td></tr>";
        $message .= "</table>";
        $message .= "</body></html>";
$recipient = "recipient@example.com";
$subject = "Contact Form from CorbisGlobal Web";
$mailheader .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$mailheader .= "From: " . strip_tags($_POST['mail']) . "\r\n";
$mailheader .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $message, $mailheader) or die (error);
header("Location: thankyou.php"); 
exit; 
?>
```

Comment: A 500 error = Server error (probably some PHP error). Check your error log or turn display errors on and you will get a proper error message you can share with us. Here you can see how to turn it on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display

Comment: Btw, why are you storing all the post values in variables, and then use the post variable directly anyway, later on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error is probably on the middle row:

```
$subject = "Contact Form from CorbisGlobal Web";
$mailheader .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$mailheader .= "From: " . strip_tags($_POST['mail']) . "\r\n";
```

You didn't create the variable `$mailheader` before you're adding more text to it.

Turn error reporting on and you'll have meaningful error messages that will help you solve most of your problems.

Also, you're doing this:

```
mail($recipient, $subject, $message, $mailheader) or die (error);
```

`or die (error)`, you probably didn't define the `error` constant, and there is no variable with this name in the code you have shown us. To check if the `mail` function has accepted your input, you can do this:

```
if (mail($recipient, $subject, $message, $mailheader)){
    header("Location: thankyou.php"); 
}
else{
    die("Error sending email");
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is probably it (assuming the OP didn't omit this)

Comment: I seriously doubt that would lead to a http 500 error.

Comment: There is also a problem with his "or die" function, I have added it to the answer.

Comment: When turn on the errors, appear that:

Warning: join(): Invalid arguments passed in /srv/www/corbis-www/mail.php on line 12

Warning: join(): Invalid arguments passed in /srv/www/corbis-www/mail.php on line 30
Error sending email

When i delet this line.. Die.. error sending email...

Comment: Don't forget the `exit;` after the `header('location: ...');` (that will probably not fix your error, but you should always have an `exit;` after a redirect-header.)

Comment: @EmilianoMaza - Does `$_POST['services']` actually contain an array?

Comment: it's stranger that, if a test in other server the same code, it's works... http://emilianomaza.com.ar/contact-form-corbis/contact.php

@MagnusEriksson you mean form code? nop

Comment: I mean, you're sending `$services` as the second param in your `join()`-call. If that's not an array, you will get the error you just showed. `join()` is an alias for `implode()`.. here's the manual for it: http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php